# How do change Heroku 500 error message?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

How do I change heroku 500 error message and how to do a redirect to root_url ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an addon available, see http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-error-pages